# Increase Speed In SQL Big Data

Tags: sql, performance, bigdata

I have a table of 50 million records with 17 columns. I want to publish data into some tables. I have built some tables for this.
I wrote a sql script for this work. But the speed of this script is very low.
The main problem is that Before I want to insert a record in a table, I must check the table to not exists that record.
Of course I already done some optimization in my code. For example I replace cursor with while statement. But still the speed is very low.
What can I do to increase the speed and optimization?

Comment: update your question add  your tables  schema  .. your query and the explain plain

Comment: Also add the actual RDBMS. SQL Server? Oracle? MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

> I must check the table to not exists that record.

Let the database do the work via a unique constraint or index.  Decide on the columns that cannot be identical and run something like:

```
create unique index unq_t_col1_col2_col3 on t(col1, col2, col3);
```

The database will then return an error if you attempt to insert a duplicate.

This is standard functionality and should be available in any database.  But, you should tag your question with the database you are using and provide more information about what *you* mean by a duplicate.

Comment: ok! But there is another problem here: If SQL could not insert a new record because of duplicate, I need the table rowId (Primary Key Field) for rest of the code script.

Comment: Then, search it using the unique key. That table seek is instantaneous when there's a unique key.

Comment: @irshmd2 . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have another question, ask it as a *new* question.  TheImpaler's suggestion is a good one.  However, depending on the database, there may be other solutions as well.